# Strike-through or edit?

Tags: discussion, edits

Sometimes other users point out corrections to answers in comments. What is the best practice when correcting your own answers?

A) Edit your answer and remove the incorrect/outdate contents, possibly making the comments odd and / or hard to follow, or

B) Edit your answer and use <strike>strike-through</strike> to make the correction visible, leaving some junk in the answer

Is there a rule / agreement on this one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Comments are disposable; edit your answer to be readable without requiring context. The full edit history is available to those curious about how the answer was changed over time.

If you are bothered by a comment, you can always flag it as obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

<s>There is no strict rule for this.</s>

It depends.

If you want the original content to be preserved, strike away. Not whole chunks of code of course, only when it's matter of few lines, just to save people the need to go to the revisions.

If you don't care that much for the original  content, just edit it out. Martjin [gave a good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234607/152859) regarding why you shouldn't consider existing comments when doing it.

All in all, there is no rule. Some people edit out, some keep and strike through. As long as the final result is readable and useful, it's all good.